# debouncing: How does it work if the variable inside is always truthy

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand *how* a debounce function works.  I added some logging statements in it when I was trying to understand and it seems that `timeoutId` will always have a value.  If I make a setTimeout and assign it to a variable, that variable seems to always be truthy even if I clear the timeout:

```
let foo = setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("");
},5000);

clearTimeout(foo);

foo   // some Number value
!!foo // true
```

so for this debounce function, it confuses me as to what it is actually doing

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
   
    let timeoutId;

    return function(...args) {
        console.log("timeout id is " , timeoutId);
        if (timeoutId) {
           clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
           fn(...args)
        }, delay)
    }
}
```

Comment: what part don't you understand exactly? I assume the rest operator and the fn call?

Comment: @EugenSunic no, that part I get ...i don't get how `clearTimeout` is ever reached if `timeoutId` is always truthy

Comment: @MauirceA — `if (truthy)` runs whatever is in the `if` so `clearTimeout` will always run (except the first time when there is no timeout).

Comment: Clearing the timeout does not clear the variable. Add `timeoutId = null` the line below `clearTimeout(timeoutId)` to also set the variable to `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeoutId won't have a value the **first** time the function is invoked, but that's by-the-by.

---

The logic is:

- Stop any previous attempt to do this
- Now do this in *delay* seconds

So if you click (let's assume the function is called by a click) once, *delay* seconds later the thing will happen.

However, if you click once (it will start that timer) and **then** click again quickly: it will cancel the timer so *delay* seconds after the first click the thing **won't** happen (but it also starts a new timer so  *delay* seconds after the **second** click the thing **will** happen… unless there is a third click… etc.).

Comment: thanks Quentin...I think my misunderstanding was _when_ the setTimeout is triggered.  I thought the `first` click would set the timeout and then all subsequent ones would have to be ignored until the setTimeout executed.  I did not grasp that if the setTimout didn't finish, any subsequent click would "reset" it.